# Wordpress: wp_create_category may take 20 seconds to complete

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I inherited a `PHP` and Wordpress project where terms (taxonomy = 'category') is used to record every single data points in the system. We have over 30,000 rows in the terms table. Yes, I know- It's a crazy decision, but I didn't make it. I am just stuck with it.

I have a certain script that tries to make fixes to several hundred posts. The fix required me to use `wp_create_category`, and `wp_set_post_categories`. My problem is speed. It seems every single call to `wp_create_category` updates some kind of caching or re-loads/re-writes everything in the terms from scratch. I cannot explain why it takes 20-30 seconds for each single call to complete.

Other than the obvious wrong of using terms to store every data point in the system..... what am I doing wrong to get those slow speeds?

Is there a way to "disable" something prior to running several hundreds `wp_create_category` and `wp_set_post_categories` that would make my life less of a waiting hell?

Comment: You need to profile it, to see what db queries could be slow.

Comment: *I have a certain script that tries to make fixes to several hundred posts.* - maybe you should add its code to your question. Typical troubleshooting steps like disabling all plugins (and enabling them back one at a time, while trying on your script), and switching to the standard themes, might also help you identify what the real problem is and the causes.

Comment: You can also install [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) and inspect the database queries *after* running your script..

Comment: I did. There no query that lasts 20 seconds. Those calls are creating a chain of bottlenecks, but not in the database. It did however reveal interesting things like how Wordpress DELETES and ADDS options upon merely loading up the landing page. A single page load costs 76 individual database queries. It's absolutely crazy. Justifies my efforts of running away from Wordpress toward developing a custom replacement with a proper stack.

Comment: @SallyCJ I am not really using wordpress in my code with the exception of `wp_create_category` and `wp_set_post_categories` -- I have shown beyond a doubt that a a single call of one of those can take 20 seconds to return. but trying to move away from the theme for a second and turning off plug-ins sounds like a good test. Is there a command that disables them all? or do I actually have to go to the interface and disable them one by one?

Comment: @JasonGenX if you give me remote access through Teamviewer or a copy of the project I can solve it for you.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but it's far too complex, and spanning too many machines to do that. I'll just have to use what I got to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a WP expert, my forte is more databases.  That said, this looks like a database (or interaction-with-database) problem.

My guess is that you could be better served by looking directly at the database WP is built on and importing your categories more efficiently.  The categories are inserted in a chain that starts with [Create Category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_category/), [moves to insert category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_category/), [and finally seems to insert a term.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/) (note three separate links, with source)  The [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) has a database diagram that shows the 'terms' in a series of satellite tables to the posts.

So, if you insert a single term directly and find the structure / data information you want to mimic (I suggest recreating or linking to the appropriate information in wp_termmeta and wp_term_taxonomy) you will end up with a exponentially faster process.

The other option is to get your code right, start it running, and go home for the night sometime.  This is probably actually simpler.

Comment: The problem is when you inject terms into the database directly -- they are not absorbed by Wordpress' term cache and are not available to the system. It sometime takes hours for direct database changes to take hold. On the other hand, using wp_* api to inject new terms into the system allows them to be immediately available, but takes 20+ seconds to complete. I suspect the entire cache is being re-loaded with every new term injection. I wish there was a way to turn off the cache auto-update, inject a 1000 new terms, and then re-activate it to re-cache to have it learn them.

Comment: Interesting.  Did you try setting the wp_cache setting in wp-settings.php to false?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Cache

Comment: Why not do your update in two stages: one where you insert all the terms and then one where you apply them?

Comment: And how do you "Apply" them once injected to the database outside of the wp_* functions?

Comment: My assumption is that WP operates on top of the database and if you put data into the database that looks like WP inserted it, then reboot / restart / reset the WP cache you can see the tags as you have created them. If you're working with a very large dataset like this, do you have multiple servers available so you can stage your release?  Or do you have scheduled downtime?  You're talking, no matter what, about running a fairly risky process on a live server; many of the issues you're mentioning could be worked around using infrastructure.

Comment: The changes are atomic, and unrelated to each other. if I'm at 10% of them done, the system is still stable, data-wise. It's just the speed of the wp_ commands that drove me crazy. I could not figure out why it takes 20 seconds - and from query monitoring I've done, the bottleneck is clearly NOT the database. It's not even breaking a sweat.

Comment: Yeah, it's much more likely the processing on the wp side of the cache load combined with wp maintaining its uptime.

Comment: So in theory. If I were to turn WP_CACHE to false.... do the job... and turn it back to WP_CACHE true -- that would have a good effect on speed?

Comment: You could try it for five entries and see if it helped. You might have the same update problems as with inserting directly into the database, though. You might try contacting WordPress directly through their forums or Google group or whatever for this, you know. It's a pretty specific question.

Comment: Also, to get these settings to apply you may need to restart Apache or WordPress anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I'm not enough of a specific expert to do more than explain the steps I'd take.

Answer (score 0):

wp_create_category checks whether the term exists before it performs the insert operation. so in your case, if you are having 30k rows in terms and not indexed properly this would have some effects on your performance. You can optimise and re-index the database and test again if this is still not effective and if you are sure you are inserting unique categories then try calling `wp_insert_category( array('cat_name' => $cat_name, 'category_parent' => $parent) );`